# Customize Instead of Update Trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

Hi i have the following Trigger:

```
    ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[BOOKVERNR_UPDATE]
ON [dbo].[BUCHUNG]
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS

BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

        INSERT INTO [BUCHUNG] (BOOKUID, BOOKVERNR, BUCHUNGSART_ID, VERANSTALTER, PERSONAL_ID,
        OPTIONSNUMMER, BUCHUNGSSTATUS, PERSONENZAHL, SERIE, THEMA, STORNO, UPDATE_DATE, UPDATE_USER, BEMERKUNG, V_EMAIL, V_TELEFON,
        KOSTENSTELLE, SERIENBOOKUID, THEMA_ENABLED, ABTEILUNG, LIEFERRAUM, PERSONENZAHLEXTERN, ABRECHNUNG, KSTR, RECHKONTO, RECHKST, RECHDST, URSPRUNG_ORIGINAL, ORIGINAL_ID)

        SELECT i.BOOKUID, '0', i.BUCHUNGSART_ID, i.VERANSTALTER, i.PERSONAL_ID,
        i.OPTIONSNUMMER, i.BUCHUNGSSTATUS, i.PERSONENZAHL, i.SERIE, i.THEMA, i.STORNO, GETDATE(), i.UPDATE_USER, i.BEMERKUNG, i.V_EMAIL, i.V_TELEFON,
        i.KOSTENSTELLE, i.SERIENBOOKUID, i.THEMA_ENABLED, i.ABTEILUNG, i.LIEFERRAUM, i.PERSONENZAHLEXTERN, i.ABRECHNUNG, i.KSTR, i.RECHKONTO, i.RECHKST, i.RECHDST, i.URSPRUNG_ORIGINAL,
        i.ORIGINAL_ID


        FROM INSERTED i
        JOIN DELETED d ON i.ID = d.ID
        WHERE i.BOOKVERNR <> d.BOOKVERNR


SET NOCOUNT OFF;
END
```

The trigger copies an entire row with a new ID if an Update on "BOOKVERNR" happens. A new row is only inserted if an Update happens on "BOOKVERNR".

My Problem ist that with that trigger i can't Update the other colums except with for Example "IF UPDATE (BOOKUID)". But that is not what i want.

Is there a way to customize the trigger, so that i can Update all the other columns,without using "IF UPDATE" for each column?

Comment: So instead of using a single column to check for updates, you actually want to check all columns? If so, have you thought about using a CHECKSUM column and putting the trigger on that?

Comment: Yes i want to check all the columns for updates. How can i do that with the CHECKSUM column?

Comment: Check this for an idea of how to add a CHECKSUM column to a table. 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189788.aspx

Ensure you create the CHECKSUM over all columns, which should ensure that when any of the columns are updated, the CHECKSUM will change, thus firing the trigger you put on the CHECKSUM column.

Comment: Maybe you can help me out with that. i have done something but i dont know how to go on

Comment: SELECT CHECKSUM(BOOKUID, BOOKVERNR, BUCHUNGSART_ID, VERANSTALTER, PERSONAL_ID,
        OPTIONSNUMMER, BUCHUNGSSTATUS, PERSONENZAHL, SERIE, THEMA, STORNO, UPDATE_DATE, UPDATE_USER, BEMERKUNG, V_EMAIL, V_TELEFON,
        KOSTENSTELLE, SERIENBOOKUID, THEMA_ENABLED, ABTEILUNG, LIEFERRAUM, PERSONENZAHLEXTERN, ABRECHNUNG, KSTR, RECHKONTO, RECHKST, RECHDST, URSPRUNG_ORIGINAL, ORIGINAL_ID) 
        AS ChecksumValue FROM BUCHUNG

Comment: Actually, you're issuing a SELECT statement. You should add a checksum column to the table:

ALTER TABLE BUCHER ADD BUCHER_CHECKSUM AS CHECKSUM(BOOKUID, BOOKVERNR, BUCHUNGSART_ID, VERANSTALTER, PERSONAL_ID, OPTIONSNUMMER, BUCHUNGSSTATUS, PERSONENZAHL, SERIE, THEMA, STORNO, UPDATE_DATE, UPDATE_USER, BEMERKUNG, V_EMAIL, V_TELEFON, KOSTENSTELLE, SERIENBOOKUID, THEMA_ENABLED, ABTEILUNG, LIEFERRAUM, PERSONENZAHLEXTERN, ABRECHNUNG, KSTR, RECHKONTO, RECHKST, RECHDST, URSPRUNG_ORIGINAL, ORIGINAL_ID).

Comment: ok and how can i customize the above trigger so he fires on the CHECKSUM column? Thanks

Comment: Change the "WHERE i.BOOKVERNR <> d.BOOKVERNR" part to "WHERE i.BUCHER_CHECKSUM <> d.BUCHER_CHECKSUM"

Comment: Note, I haven't tested the above, as I don't have the table structure, but that should do the trick.

Comment: hmm the problem will be, that if i say WHERE i.BUCHER_CHECKSUM <> d.BUCHER_CHECKSUM, the trigger copies a new row everytime a column gets updated. But the trigger should only copy new row if BOOKVERNR gets an update. If another column gets updated the trigger should update the old row.

Comment: Ah. I misunderstood things then. Based on that, I'd think you would have to alter your original trigger. Add an IF clause around the code you had which checks if the BOOKVERNR changed. That ensures it only inserts when that is true. Then write an ELSE statement that performs the update on the table. 

Something like UPDATE BUCHUNG SET BUCHUNGSART_ID = I.BUCHUNGSART_ID, VERANSTALTER = i.VERANSTALTER ... FROM BUCHUNG, INSERTED i WHERE BUCHING.BOOKVERNR = i.BOOKVERNR